# Let $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$ except when $x=0$. Show that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same Fourier Coefficients?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Question:

Let $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$ except when $x=0$. Show that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same Fourier Coefficients?

My Attempt:

So I've tried to calculate the fourier coefficients but i can only show that $a_0^f=a_0^g$, not $a_n^f=a_n^g$ and $b_0^f=b_0^g$. I also tried letting $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)=0$ but I don't think that works since $h(0)=f(0)-g(0)\neq0$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The Fourier coefficients are obtained by integration, and this last doesn't change if we change the function's value on finitely many points (or even at infinite points...under some restrictions).

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are given by
$$
\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx
$$

So changing one point of $f$ does not change the coefficients.

On the other hand, if $f$ is *continuous* on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and $\hat{f}(n)=0$ for all $n$, then $f\equiv 0$.